# android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1 in sqlitedatabse in android

Tags: java, android

I have a query in my database like this:

```
Cursor c= ourDB.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(odometer) AS odometer FROM tripmileagetable WHERE car='abdul' AND date LIKE '2012-07%'", null);
        if(c.getCount()<=0){
            return 0;

        }else{

            int sum= c.getInt(0);
            Log.i("Sum of odometer", ""+sum);
            return sum;

        }
```

and its giving me this exception. If I write this in the else section:

```
int sum= c.getColumnIndex("odometer");
            Log.i("Sum of odometer", ""+sum);
            return sum;
```

then this returns 0, but when I put 0 it gives me the exception, I am unable to find out my fault. Can any one help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed out `c.moveToFirst();` that is why your cursor is giving exception as by default it points index -1.

Answer (score 0):

You should first check if cursor has any elements and move it to first index. In this case your db didnt return any results.

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
 int sum= c.getInt(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestions but handy:

1. Before starting work with Cursor, i would check whether its null or not
2. Move the cursor to 1st index
3. Instead of mentioning c.getInt(0); , i would use c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("FirstColumnName")));

For example:

```
if (cursor != null) {
    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            temp.add(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("FirstColumnName"))); // "FirstColumnName" is the field name(column) of the Table                 
        } while (cur.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try  this

```
cursor.moveToFirst();

while(cursor.moveToNext() )
{
   // YOUR CODE HERE
}
```